# Is it possible to set multiple JSON-RPC users?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

I am passing multiple `-rpcuser` and `-rpcpassword` options, but the last user is the one that's working ! I was assuming that I can set multiple JSON-RPC users.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!
I used share/rpcauth.py script in bitcoin core to generate two users and passed the output multiple times using `-rpcauth` argument.

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/master/share/rpcauth/rpcauth.py

python3 rpcauth.py my-username  my-password
```